# Azure Billing API Issue

Tags: python, azure, azure-billing-api

I am using the Azure Invoice API which has asks for the following parameters
[https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/**{billingAccountName}**/billingProfiles/**{billingProfileName}**/invoices/**{invoiceName}**?api-version=2019-10-01-preview](https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/**%7BbillingAccountName%7D**/billingProfiles/**%7BbillingProfileName%7D**/invoices/**%7BinvoiceName%7D**?api-version=2019-10-01-preview)

but after having all the parameters and running my Python code, I am facing an error which is defined below:

> {'code': 'NotFound', 'message': 'The resource or one of its
> dependencies could not be found.'}

and I have given the Billing reader access to the Service Principle that I am using for generating access token.
Is there anything required other than this role for reading Billing data of Azure?
Is there a possibility that I am entering wrong parameters?

We are expecting to get the invoice data for Azure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @MEHRAB VERMA Could you provide your Python code in the question?

Comment: Are you able to fire the rest api call via postman? If that is working then we know it is a problem with your code. Else it will be something with your parameters in the rest API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am facing an error defined below {'code': 'NotFound', 'message': 'The resource or one of its dependencies could not be found.'}

The above error occurs maybe you have passed incorrect parameters, incorrect permissions, or issues with the API itself.

You can use the below Python code to fetch invoice details from a user with **`billing reader`** role. it supports only users and groups to get the info of invoice details.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Roles:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.billing import BillingManagementClient


def main():
    client = BillingManagementClient(
        credential=credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id="Your-subscription-id",
    )

    response = client.invoices.get(
        billing_account_name="<your-billing-account-name>",
        invoice_name="<Your-invoice-name>",
    )
    print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

1. [Invoices - Get - REST API (Azure Billing) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2020-05-01/invoices/get?tabs=Python#creditnote)
2. [Manage access to Azure billing - Microsoft Cost Management | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/manage-billing-access#give-others-access-to-view-billing-information)